# Firestore.settings() requires its first argument to be of type object but it was a custom object

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

I can't call the firebase.firestore().settings() function as I'm getting some "requires its first argument to be of type object" error:

```
firebase.firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true })
```

I don't understand this error, but as a workaround I tried to create an object thus:

```
const firestoreSettings = Object.create({ timestampsInSnapshots: true })
firebase.firestore().settings(firestoreSettings)
```

This didn't work either.

Where does this error come from and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

you are confusing the namespaces; this should do the trick

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
   firebase.initializeApp(YOUR_CONFIG_OBJECT_GOES_HERE)
}
const firestore = firebase.firestore()
const settings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true }
firestore.settings(settings) // notice it is firestore instead of firestore()
```

PD: This is not required anymore... try updating your sdk version to the last one :)

Comment: You mean updating to Firebase 6.1.1? If so I tried but it didn't work better. Also I don't understand what "admin" is (getting "admin is not defined" error)

Comment: my bad I just update the answer, `admin` is a convention... I cannot recall after which version it was removed, but now it is not a problem any longer... anyway, check the updated sample, it should work

Comment: Thanks but I'm still getting "admin is not defined", also getting "Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app)". I've been stuck on this firebase thing for 5 days now, what an absolute pain in the ***

Comment: i just made the last update, since you are asking this question on several posts, you should keep it in one place only, also consider that maybe the error is not on firebase side but something on your setup, check your versions, make sure you are using the last one

Comment: Back to `...requires its first argument to be of type object` error now. As I said I'm using the last version of Firebase. About multiple threads it's a tricky matter because I'm dealing with 2 complete different errors and so far I'm getting either one or the other...

Comment: Did u notice that Im using firestore.settings instead of firestore().settings... ?

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';

const config = {
    apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxx',
    authDomain: 'xxxxxxxxx',
    ......
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

const db = firebase.firestore();

const settings = {
    timestampsInSnapshots: true
};
db.settings(settings);

//....
```

---

As indicated in the other answer, note that you don't need use the `timestampsInSnapshots` setting anymore, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Settings#optional-timestamps-insnapshots

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that this issue was tagged with `nuxt.js`. I came across this issue recently when initializing firestore with settings in a Nuxt app. I solved the issue by making sure that `firestore().settings()` was only called client side - not server side.